# You closed my question as duplicate when it obviously isn't

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

Question in question:

[I downloaded a shell executable and man pages from a source I trust. Where should I put them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401632/i-downloaded-a-shell-executable-and-man-pages-from-a-source-i-trust-where-shoul?noredirect=1#comment557007_401632)

You closed it as duplicates of question which only mention where to put the executable, not the man pages. You're definitely being a bit too trigger-happy with closing questions - maybe read the whole question title before doing that?

Comment: Sometimes mistakes are made when closing questions.  It's good you brought it here to discuss it.  However, insulting people who had no malice toward you is not very good and not very community-oriented.  As you've seen, mistakes can be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this up in Meta. One of the answers on the original questions mentions

> if the package/application follows unix standards, then install it to /usr/local/. There will be no surprises in the package and you can definitely expect a sub-directory structure like bin, etc, include, share, and so on.

which I assumed to be sufficient to answer the question. But I agree that deriving the specific path for a man page might not be that easy after all :-)

Question is reopened.